# setting search_path to role doesn't seem to work in postgres

Tags: postgresql, schema, role

I've created a backend api that connects to `postgres` and performs various queries.

I've created a **specific user** (role + can login privilege) for that backend api:

`backend_api_user`

I've also dropped the public **schema** in favor of a new one to be used by a backend api:

`apischema`

In order to avoid having to prefix each query made by the backend api, I **changed the search path** like below:

```sql
ALTER ROLE backend_api_user SET search_path TO apischema;
```

Problem is that I need to prefix references to tables in the backend api queries. So something is not working even if it looks okay from postgres'perspective:

```sql
SELECT usename, useconfig FROM pg_user WHERE usename='backend_api_user'
```

| username | useconfig |
| --- | --- |
| backend_api_user | {search_path=apischema} |

Side note: I'm using postgres and pgadmin4. Both are docker containers that I run using docker desktop for mac.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating the `backend_api_user` role, I just added the following grants

```sql
GRANT INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE ON table1, table2, table3, table4 TO backend_api_user;
```

But with `postgres`, giving privilege on a table doesn't imply that you have some on the schema. And the `backend_api_user` didn't have any grant on the `apischema`, especially the `USAGE` grant ... Eventually, this one-liner has done the job.

```sql
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA apischema TO backend_api_user;
```

Answer (score 1):

It will only work for connections that were established *after* you ran `ALTER ROLE`, so restart the application. Also, the setting will only work for connections as `backend_api_user` itself – membership in the role is not enough.

Comment: I've restarted the app and I'm using the backend_api_user :/

Comment: Then the only possibility is that your application changes the `search_path` after the user connects.